# use dynamic range in countif formula

Tags: excel, countif

I have this sheet with data:
[image: count and search range example]

the search range (row 3) is filled until column AM and the count range (row 4 and lower) is only filled until column R (more columns will be filled in time)

I need to have a formula to use in my count if formula to find the last filled column.

So in this case the the search range for the countif formula has to be:
=countif(C3:R3;C4:R4)

but when column S is filled, the formula should automatically use column S instead of R. etc.

the formula is used to calculate an average of the scores/percentage for a certain skill (e.g. optellen+aftrekken, tafels, tijd). So just counting the arguments in row 4 or lower is not enough. It also has to count how many times the given skill is found in the applying range (Column C to R, C to S etc).

I have a combinated formula to have the complete first parameter for the countif formula:

```
="'invoer optie2 (2)'!C$3:"&(ADRES(3;AANTALARG('invoer optie2 (2)'!4:4)+1;2;1))
```

(the formula is in dutch).

the result is this:

```
'invoer optie2 (2)'!C$3:R$3
```

This is the part I need for my countif formula. I keep struggling on how to use this in the countif formula so it uses it a the search range.

How can I convert this "string" to the range in the countif formula?

Comment: You would need to wrap that in INDIRECT()

Comment: But ultimately `=COUNTIF('invoer optie2 (2)'!3:3,"WhatYouWant")` will be quicker than the volatile ADDRESS and INDIRECT.  There really is no reason to try to limit the search range in COUNTIFS.

Comment: in my case, it does. because the search range is filled until column AM and the count range is only filled until column R (which fills slowly in time) (I use it to calculate an average based on the counted items in the then filled range. I will add an image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use ADDRESS and INDIRECT as they are Volatile.

Instead use INDEX:

```
=COUNTIFS('invoer optie2 (2)'!C$3:INDEX('invoer optie2 (2)'!$3:$3,MATCH(1E+99,'invoer optie2 (2)'!4:4)),"WhatYouWant")
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try your suggestion, but need some time to do so...Will be continued soon I hope.

Comment: tried but doesn't seem to work for me. added some info the question.

Comment: finally managed to get it working! thank you! =AANTAL.ALS('invoer optie2 (2)'!C$3:INDEX('invoer optie2 (2)'!$3:$3;VERGELIJKEN(1E+99;'invoer optie2 (2)'!4:4));B2) (dutch formula)